# Hadoop installation and configuration: multiple versions side-by-side on same host

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

Can we install different versions of Hadoop on the same system  in pseudo distributed mode?

Actually I want to explore features of different version of hadoop-1.x and hadoop-2.x and I have configured hadoop-1.x and hadoop-2.x on two different systems running with Linux. Is there any way to configure then on the same machine?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to install multiple versions of the Hadoop software side-by-side on the same host.

- Extract the different versions of the Hadoop software into separate sub-directories.
- Create separate configuration files (core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, yarn-site.xml, etc.) for the different versions, and keep these sets of files in separate directories.
- Make sure to configure different directories for things that use local storage, such as `dfs.namenode.name.dir` and `dfs.datanode.data.dir` in hdfs-site.xml.  The two versions should have data isolated from one another.  Alternatively, if you want to attempt to share data between two different versions, and just run one version at a time, then you might be able to achieve that.  Depending on which software versions are involved, you might run into data incompatibilities or a need to run the upgrade commands.
- If you want to run multiple versions simultaneously, make sure they are configured with distinct server ports for things like `dfs.namenode.rpc-address` in hdfs-site.xml and `yarn.server.resourcemanager.address` in yarn-site.xml.
- When invoking commands, set environment variables like `HADOOP_HOME` and `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` to control which version to execute and which configurations to use.

Everything above works fine for a manually deployed installation, such as using the Apache Hadoop distro.  For Bigtop distros or vendor distros, the rpm/deb/etc. packaging might be less tolerant of side-by-side deployment.